# Forgot password - Only on some Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, login, password

The forgot password link appears on "Ask Different" but not on "Stack Overflow" or "Meta Stack Exchange"
Why is this?
Surely you should expand the forgot password feature to all sites.
Is this a bug with my web browser (Safari on iPhone)?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoIs9.png <-- it does show for me ...

Comment: Works for me as well...

Comment: Really? It shows on Stack Overflow for you? I wonder why it is only visible to me on some sites.

Comment: Yes, on SO and MSE. Do you have any userscript installed?

Comment: What is userscript?

Comment: @LegendusMaximus are you using some adblocker?

Comment: I don't know if it makes us any wiser, but: *[Userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript)* - *"A userscript (or user script) is a program, usually written in JavaScript, for modifying web pages to augment browsing. On desktop browsers such as Firefox, they are enabled by use of a userscript manager browser extension such as [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)."*

Comment: No I don’tt have any userscript